# How to set video title - Youtube UploadWidget

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to set the title of the video being uploaded and I'm using ajax to get the value of an input field, but can't seem to get it to work. I think the problem is due to the jquery code I use to get the input field value. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks

This is my code

```
  <script>
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  widget = new YT.UploadWidget('widget', {
    width: 500,
    events: {
      'onUploadSuccess': onUploadSuccess,
      'onProcessingComplete': onProcessingComplete,
      'onApiReady': onApiReady
    }
  });
}

function onApiReady(event){
  widget.setVideoTitle($('#title').val());
  widget.setVideoPrivacy('unlisted');
}
  <script>
```

Comment: .setVidoeTitle seems right. are you sure $('#title').val() has a val

Comment: The .val() used to get the values of input, select and textarea. if title is a div it wont work

Comment: Yes I tested it to make sure there is a value and I am trying to get it from an input.

Comment: is the onApiReady firing?

Comment: i provided a solution. take a look. its not a good solution if you ask me but it works.

Answer (score 0):

the `onApiReady` function is fired before you are able to enter anything in the textbox.

i have resolved this with probably most convoluted way. I am storing a cookie on the user when they submit the title. And then, I retrieve the title back after page reloads and pass it to `widget.setVideoTitle`

here is jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/BbDwj/